# Complicated Excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a complicated situation in Excel.

I have the following rows:

```
ID   Name     ID    Name
14353         12345 John Adams
12345         43215 Barbara Brooke
43215         34762 George John
              34563 Melinda Bates
```

How do I get the data from the Name column to move under the empty Name column in cases where the IDs match?

Of course, the above example is very small, I have thousands of these to do...

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the VLOOKUP formula

Comment: Have a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel/4327/vlookup-function#t=201708021208427953221

Comment: By matching ID, do you mean on the same row, or an ID on the left can be found somewhere in the ID column on the right (they're independent lists)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$F$5,2,FALSE),"")


   A            B                   
   ID          Name 
   14353    =Iferror(Vlookup(A2,$E$2:$F$5,2,False),"")                
   12345    John Adams             
   43215    Barbara Brooke
```

Your Data is in E and F column:

```
E          F
ID        Name
12345   John Adams
43215   Barbara Brooke
34762   George John
34563   Melinda Bates
```

Change E2:F5 to correspond the reference of your data but keep $ for fixed references and drag the formula down
Iferror will return empty cell if the ID is not found in your data